# How to web user interface + node.js and express routing

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I have server with node.js + express for routing. When I do requests like `http://mydomain.com/photos`, `http://mydomain.com/photos/123`, etc I got JSON answer. This is OK and exactly what I need. So RESTful API is ready. But this is just data and I need also to process this data and show it as webUI (html, css, angularjs).

How to implement webUI for this purpose properly?

I need to have unique independent server API in order to use it for different clients: browser web site, mobile apps, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want something like the [MEAN](http://www.mean.io/) stack: MongoDB + Express + AngularJS + NodeJS.

Your client (AngularJS) is being delivered somehow (static hosting, express, cdn, nginx, etc) and then performs REST requests to an external server (Rails, Express, Php, etc) that has CORS enabled if lives in a different domain. This structure is known as **Single Page Applications (SPA)**, where a single big HTTP request is loaded in order to interact with a backend.

That being said, this is nothing new... things like CouchDB, SammyJS and so on had been working on this for a couple years now.

Comment: Thanks) So, I have routing from server side for API. Do I also need to have similar/separated routing for client?

Comment: Usually, routing on the server side for SPAs are REST resources. So if in your client you go to domain.com:8000/user/1 you can catch that with AngularJS routing and then perform a GET request to your API endpoint with given params.